# POST Request in xamarin forms

Tags: c#, php, wordpress, xamarin.forms

I'm trying authenticate a user on WordPress using a REST API Route configured with POST method. I have already done this with it configured with the GET method but this isn't exactly safe for user authentication. So I need to send a POST request to this endpoint with the email and password I get from the login form. The code I currently have does get to the endpoint which uses the function and returns a string if I put `echo "It works"`. However if I try to echo or return the values of my POST it returns nothing.

Xamarin Code:

```
var password = Wachtwoord.Text;
var email = Email.Text;

var client = new HttpClient();
var content = new StringContent(
JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new { email = email, password = password }));
var result = await client.PostAsync("https://staging.myopinion.be/wp-json/app-endpoint/auth", content).ConfigureAwait(false);
if (result.IsSuccessStatusCode)
{
    var tokenJson = await result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    var test = tokenJson;
}
```

WordPress Functions code:

```
function authenticate_user(WP_REST_Request $request) {
    $login = $_POST;
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $password = $login['password'];
    echo $email;
}
```

Comment: are you saying that `tokenJson` is empty/null?  What happens if you test using Postman?

Comment: when debugging tokenJson is "" after it should have been set. if I debug with echo "string" it's value is said string. I have never used Postman the rest API also isn't mine it's a plugin I downloaded to my WordPress site, I just tweaked it a bit to add extra endpoints.

Comment: I would suggest testing the API with Postman to verify that it is returning what you expect

Comment: Might be irrelevant, but I have run into situations where adding a final slash to URL avoided a redirect that dropped content: `"https://staging.myopinion.be/wp-json/app-endpoint/auth/"`. Worth a quick test. Its more obvious with Postman - you can actually see the redirect, iirc.

Comment: Adding a slash did not seem to work, I'm looking into postman now

Comment: Does it work with postman  @Stapyman?

Comment: I haven't had much time to work on the project since making this post, but yes I have figured out what was wrong using postman